# Show that $[2x]+[2y] \geq [x]+[y]+[x+y]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Prove that $[2x]+[2y] \geq [x]+[y]+[x+y]$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

The $[]$ symbol is the greatest integer or floor function.

I have proved this fact by cases, but I stumbled upon what I believe to be another way to prove the above inequality, and I was wondering if my sequence of statements are legitimate.

I make use of two lemmas that I have proved

**Lemma 1.**   *If $x$ is a real number and m is an integer, then $[x+m] = [x]+m$*.

**Lemma 2.**   *$\displaystyle [x]+\left[x+\frac{1}{2} \right] = [2x]$*.

My proof begins with an "obvious" statement

$$x+y \leq x+y+1$$

I then take the floor of the inequality to get

$$[x+y] \leq [x+y]+1$$             (1)

which is true in virtue of ***lemma 1.***

Furthermore, if I add the following statements

$$[x+1/2] \leq x + 1/2$$
$$[y+1/2] \leq y + 1/2$$

I procure

$$\left[x+\frac{1}{2} \right]+\left[y+\frac{1}{2}\right] \leq x+y+1$$

which by definition of the floor function renders the equation

$$[x+y]+1 = \left[x+\frac{1}{2} \right]+\left[y+\frac{1}{2} \right]$$        (2)

Substituting (2) for (1), I have

$$[x+y] \leq \left[x+\frac{1}{2} \right]+\left[y+\frac{1}{2} \right]$$

I then add $[x]$ and $[y]$ to the above inequality to produce

$$[x]+[y]+[x+y] \leq [x]+\left[x+\frac{1}{2} \right]+[y]+\left[y+\frac{1}{2} \right]$$

And in virtue of ***Lemma 2,*** the right hand side of the inequality becomes

$$[x]+[y]+[x+y] \leq [2x]+[2y].$$

I personally don't see anything wrong, except maybe for the implication made to establish (2).

Solving these kinds of problems is solely for personal gratification, so I will greatly appreciate feedback.

Thanx.

Comment: The step "by the definition of the floor function renders [...]" is not justified, that's only true if $[x+1/2]+[y+1/2]$ is the integer **immediately** before $x+y+1$, but if say $x=1=y$ we have the former is $2$ and $[x+y]+1$ is $3$.

Comment: Imho it will be easier to traverse through all possibilities of $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$. Either $\{x\} \geq 0.5$ or $\{x\} < 0.5$.

Comment: Ah, I see your point @AdamHughes. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't greatest integer be the **ceil** function?

Comment: @GabrielH: No, ceil($x$) is the _smallest_ integer that is $\ge x$. The OP's description "the greatest integer" is incomplete: it should say something like "$[x]$ is the greatest integer that is $\le x$". Perhaps this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative route:

Write $x=n+r$ and $y=m+s$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers and $r,s\in\left[0,1\right)$.

Then $\lfloor2x\rfloor+\lfloor2s\rfloor=2n+2m+\lfloor2r\rfloor+\lfloor2s\rfloor$
and $\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor=2n+2m+\lfloor r+s\rfloor$.

This shows that it is enough to prove $\lfloor2r\rfloor+\lfloor2s\rfloor\geq\lfloor r+s\rfloor$

For this discern the cases $r,s\in\left[0,0.5\right)$ and $r\in\left[0.5,1\right)\vee s\in\left[0.5,1\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is flawed for the reason described by Adam Hughes in his comment.  It is **not** the case that $$\lfloor x+y \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor + \lfloor y + 1/2 \rfloor$$ from the given inequality, because simply taking the floor of the inequality $$\lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor + \lfloor y + 1/2 \rfloor \le x + y + 1$$ does not automatically turn the inequality into an equality.  A simple counterexample is $x = y = 1/4$.  Another counterexample is $x = 3/4$, $y = 1/4$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=m+\theta_1$ and $y=n+\theta_2$ where $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $0\le\theta_1,\theta_2<1$
**Case I: $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $0\le\theta_2<\dfrac12$**
Now   \begin{align}
\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor&=\lfloor 2m+2\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor 2n+2\theta_2\rfloor\\
&=2m+2n\\
\end{align} since $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $0\le\theta_2<\dfrac12\implies 0\le2\theta_1<1$ and $0\le2\theta_2<1$
and   \begin{align}
\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor &=\lfloor m+\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor n+\theta_2\rfloor+\lfloor m+n+\theta_1+\theta_2\rfloor\\
&=m+n+(m+n)\\
&=2m+2n,
\end{align} since $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $0\le\theta_2<\dfrac12\implies 0\le\theta_1+\theta_2<1$

### $\color{red}{So\quad \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor=\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor}$

**Case II: $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1$**
\begin{align}
\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor&=\lfloor 2m+2\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor 2n+2\theta_2\rfloor=2m+(2n+1),
\end{align} since $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1\implies 0\le2\theta_1<1$ and $1\le2\theta_2<2$
and  since $0\le\theta_1<\dfrac12$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1\implies \dfrac12\le\theta_1+\theta_2<\dfrac32$  \begin{align}
\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor &=\lfloor m+\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor n+\theta_2\rfloor+\lfloor m+n+\theta_1+\theta_2\rfloor\\
&=m+n+(m+n)=2m+2n, \text{if}\quad\dfrac12\le\theta_1+\theta_2<1\\ 
&=2m+2n+1, \text{if}\quad 1\le\theta_1+\theta_2<\dfrac32
\end{align}

### $\color{red}{So \quad\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor\le\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor}$

**Case III: $\dfrac12\le\theta_1<1$ and $0\le\theta_2<\dfrac12$.** $\color{blue}{\textbf{[Same as Case II]}}$
**Case IV: $\dfrac12\le\theta_1<1$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1$**
\begin{align}
\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor&=\lfloor 2m+2\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor 2n+2\theta_2\rfloor=(2m+1)+(2n+1)=2m+2n+2,
\end{align} since $\dfrac12\le\theta_1<1$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1\implies 1\le2\theta_1<2$ and $1\le2\theta_2<2$
and  since $\dfrac12\le\theta_1<1$ and $\dfrac12\le\theta_2<1\implies 1\le\theta_1+\theta_2<2$  \begin{align}
\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor &=\lfloor m+\theta_1\rfloor+\lfloor n+\theta_2\rfloor+\lfloor m+n+\theta_1+\theta_2\rfloor\\
&=m+n+(m+n+1)=2m+2n+1\\
\end{align}

### $\color{red}{So \quad\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor\le\lfloor 2x\rfloor +\lfloor 2y\rfloor}$

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prove it that way, first you need to prove
[x+y]≤[x+1/2]+[y+1/2] again as your proof is flawed.

Simply think of [x]+[y] and [x+y]

If {x}+{y} < 1 then [x] + [y] = [x+y]

If {x}+{y} >= 1 then [x] + [y] = [x+y] - 1

So, [x]+[y] is at least [x+y] - 1.

-> [x+y+1]-1 = [x+y] =< [x+1/2] + [y+1/2]