# Inequality involving $\text{floor}(x)$

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to prove the following inequality $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ :

$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x + y \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor \le \lfloor 2x \rfloor + \lfloor 2y \rfloor$$
If one thing is clear for me it is that the basic definition isn't enough to prove this, I would always get an additional $1$ on the left hand side.

Thanks for your trouble.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1082211/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1920924/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clfloor%20x%20%5Crfloor%20%2B%20%5Clfloor%20x%20%2B%20y%20%5Crfloor%20%2B%20%5Clfloor%20y%20%5Crfloor%20%5Cle%20%5Clfloor%202x%20%5Crfloor%20%2B%20%5Clfloor%202y%20%5Crfloor%24&p=19)

Comment: I apologize for this.